# $(document).on("click"... only working occasionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a script that updates a variable with the last-clicked element every time a `div` with the class `furniture` gets clicked.

Unfortunately, while it seems that this does work, It only appears to be working sometimes. And as far as consistency of any sort is concerned I have been unable to find any.

```
$(document).on("click", ".furniture", function() {
    console.log("YouBeClickin'");
    if ( isCurrentElem == 1) {
        $(currentElem).removeClass("chosen")
    }
    currentElem = "#" + this.id; 
    $(currentElem).addClass( "chosen");
    isCurrentElem = 1;
   //alert(currentElem);
});
```

I am adding my `furniture` classed elements dynamically with JavaScript, otherwise I would post up the HTML. Upon inspecting the HTML, it is apparent that my `div`s to get classed with `furniture` so the problem doesn't lie there.

The click appears to never actually fire, noted not by the fact that I don't get the expected results on screen, but that nothing get's logged in my console. Again, it's not that it never happens just that it happens super infrequently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example page where this is happening?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The only way said event wouldn't be triggered is if said element didn't have the class you think it does. Provide code that re-creates your issue, otherwise this is nothing more  than a claim that can't be reproduced.

Comment: Can more than one `furniture` element have the `chosen` class?

Comment: Rather than `currentElem = "#" + this.id; $(currentElem).addClass("chosen");`, why not `$(this).addClass("chosen");`?

Comment: Where are `isCurrentElem` and `currentElem` defined?

Comment: I am a little confused, what exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @PaulRoub this handler is bound to the `document`, not directly to the `.furniture` elements.

Comment: Can u please provide your html page like this its difficult to understand what your problem is

Comment: @Mathletics $(this) would still work, see http://jsfiddle.net/apJ6u/

Comment: @Huangism of course it does. The comment I responded to was (incorrectly) suggesting that the click handler was bound directly to the `.furniture` elements.

Comment: @Mathletics oh understood, he must of removed that comment now

Comment: I have removed a couple of divs that seem to have solved the problem. It seems that they were positioned above my "furniture" elements and were interfering with my ability to click on the furniture. More than element can have the "chosen" class but not the way I have coded the JavaScript. The reason I am not using $(this) is because I need to keep a reference to the last piece of furniture clicked for later in my code when $(this) holds no reference to what I want to manipulate.

Comment: Which library are you using because .on works better with 1.9+

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
var currentFurniture; // predefine the "global"

$(document).on("click", ".furniture", function () {
    console.log("YouBeClickin'");
    if ( currentFurniture !== this ) {
        $(currentFurniture).removeClass("chosen");
        currentFurniture = this; 
        $(this).addClass("chosen");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the global is predefined about 200 lines further up in my script with all my other globals :)

Comment: that's just for the protocol ;) maybe you declared a `click` handler with `stopPropagation` on a nested element?

Comment: Got it. I believe I actually may have just been covering up the furniture classed div with a second div that was fully transparent . . .

Comment: beware with intercepting clicks using transparent elements: either firefox or ie was it, that lets clicks through without a trans.gif/png background img

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$(document).bind(function() {
    console.log("YouBeClickin'");
    if ( isCurrentElem == 1) {
        $(currentElem).removeClass("chosen")
    }
    currentElem = "#" + this.id; 
    $(currentElem).addClass( "chosen");
    isCurrentElem = 1;
   //alert(currentElem);
});
```

or with Jquery:

```
$(document).onclick(function() {
    console.log("YouBeClickin'");
    if ( isCurrentElem == 1) {
        $(currentElem).removeClass("chosen")
    }
    currentElem = "#" + this.id; 
    $(currentElem).addClass( "chosen");
    isCurrentElem = 1;
   //alert(currentElem);
});
```